# Problem receiving - confirmations stuck?

Tags: transactions

I have tried to transfer some btc being a first time user from one wallet to another (both online version). It seems the btc was sent but the receiving wallet is still showing '0' 24 hours later.

Receiving wallet does require three confirmations for funds to show but from what I have been able to find on blockchain it should have passed this point! Being a newbie I'm obviously concerned if everything is as it should be!

This is the transaction for the sending wallet, it seems to show the funds transferring in and then out:

https://blockchain.info/address/1BkJ16RfYTcPbhsdWKyKkg2pNVZKjbyfTA

This is the transactions list for the receiving wallet which currently shows '0' balance:

https://blockchain.info/address/1BkKpkHVcxoQEjGxZtHaxVPX9xuVh8ru5i

It shows the transactions as 4 so am concerned all is not right! Any advice is greatly received!

Thanks

Comment: I am unsure what your issue is, it seems that the receiving address you provided is working fine and is sending transactions within ~5 minutes of receiving them. If your problem is unresolved, could you please elaborate: what wallets you are using and what the desired effect would be.